# Electrical wire decision

Tags: home-installation

[image][image]

Please gudi me which cable will be bedt for my house electrical wiring. And also guide me which cable will be used for low electricity bill. Thanks

Comment: I think that if you are asking this question that you have no idea what the local regulations are and that you are not qualified to do the work. Call a qualified electrician.

Comment: for low electricity bills, turn off the lights during the day and when you are sleeping

Comment: "The best" depends the use of it. Read this for example http://wiki.diyfaq.org.uk/index.php/Cables

Comment: If you ask what would make more sense for wiring your house, the solid-stranded (1st pic) or the HF-litze (2nd pic), it is clearly the 1st one. It is probably much cheaper and it wil have negligible AC losses at 50 or 60 Hz. The 2nd one makes only sense at high frequency AC (e.g. above 1 kHz). At 50/60 Hz AC wire losses and related higher bill (although negligible) will be equal if the wires have the same copper cross section.

Answer (score 1):

In most countries local regulations or electrical code will specify the type and size of wire required, and what wiring practices must be followed for AC power wiring.

The size and type of wire used will have no effect on your electric bill. Your electric bill will be determined by how much electricity you use - turn off unneeded lights and appliances to minimize your bill.

Comment: Thanks alot for this nice and simple guidance. Thanks once again